# Is it possible to run a batch file when a program is launched?

Tags: windows, batch-file, launch

I have a batch file that toggles aero. Is there a way that when you open a certain program the batch file will run when it is launched and run again when the program is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, but on the Properties for the program you can tick a checkbox to do this on the compatability tab.

Find out info on what the browser is doing. Sart your program and then use Task manager to find your game (it is a real game and not some jscript web thing?).

Compatability layers are scritable.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286705

```
set __compatlayer=256Color (note wrong spelling)
```

Running a program will have same problem as setting compatability. You have to find something to run it on.

Windows can start a debugger automatically when a program is started. You can substitute any program that can start a program (as a batch can) for the debugger.

You can also run a script that triggers on program start. Task Scheduler can run tasks when certain events occur.

But you have to know what exact object to trap. Use task manager in the first instance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for a game that is launched via the browser. Seems like it only works if you open by clicking the program.